# Volvo 940 Dashboard Flashing winter Driving arrow

Tags: transmission, volvo, indicators

The flashing “winter driving” arrow on the dashboard according to the maintenance manual calls to take it to a Volvo dealer due to a transmission failure. Could this be due to cold weather, and what could I possibly do to fix the issue.

Comment: What year and model of 940 (SE, Turbo, etc.)?

Comment: What do you mean by "winter driving arrow"?

Comment: I believe this may also be the wheelspin indicator on that vehicle. If it is flashing only intermittently (e.g. under acceleration on slippery surfaces) this may be normal. If it is flashing constantly, then I'd head to a mechanic.

Comment: @mac +1 - sounds like the traction control light coming on to tell you that it's being activated.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @mac & @ChrisMcKeown ... one of your sensors is telling your computer one of your wheels has stopped spinning and therefor is activating the traction control. Figuring out which wheel sensor is bad will be tough to figure out. If you don't have the right diagnostic equipment available to you, it will require a trip to the mechanic to get it sorted.